# Will this function successfully make its data available in other contexts?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In this code excerpt, I'm trying to figure out whether the `data` variable from within the `setExtension` function will be available within the Object.keys context. Since the `setExtension` function is meant to change `data.layout` when `extension` is available.

```
function setExtension(file) {
  var data = files[file];
  if (extension) data.layout = data.layout + '.' + extension;
}

Object.keys(files).forEach(function(file){
  if (!check(file)) return;
  setExtension(file);
  debug('stringifying file: %s', file);
  var data = files[file];
  data.contents = data.contents.toString();
});
```

I would say `setExtension` does nothing because it creates `data` in its scope and it doesn't return `data`. But I'm having trouble figuring out whether I'm actually correct, or overlooking something trivial.

Comment: It doesn't return anything, but it does alter `files[file].layout`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` variable won't be available outside of it's local function scope, because it was declared with the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword and Javascript has function level scoping.

If you remove the `var` keyword, then it would be available, because it would be declared on the global object. **However, this is a [bad idea](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html), so don't do it**.

What you can do instead is return the data variable from the `setExtension` function.

```
function setExtension(file) {
  var data = files[file];
  if (extension) data.layout = data.layout + '.' + extension;
  return data;
}
```

Then you can get hold of the data variable by changing your forEach:

```
Object.keys(files).forEach(function(file){
  if (!check(file)) return;
  var data = setExtension(file);
  debug('stringifying file: %s', file);
  data.contents = data.contents.toString();
});
```

Comment: And then you would have to assign the `setExtension` function to a newly declared `data` variable right? Like: `var data = setExtension(file)`?

Comment: Wouldn't it be an expensive operation to create a `var` on every iteration? Or is that difficult to judge?

Comment: Creating a variable isn't an expensive operation in Javascript, seeing as variables are just references. You're going to be calling the `setExtension` function either way, which is more expensive.

Comment: At this point it's worth remembering that [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). If you get bogged down in trying to write performant code, then you'll end up making it harder to maintain.

Finish it, then if it runs too slowly, go back and start to profile it.